# Why isn't typeof(this) or sizeof(this) valid?

Tags: c#, this

Simple question. Why isn't the expression `typeof(this)` not valid C#? Or the expression `sizeof(this)`, as well? When I try to run a short test program, it says Type Expected, and then throws a bunch of other syntax errors. I mean, `typeof` is a method (or a keyword that you pass an argument to, not sure), and it's the same for `sizeof`, so why isn't `this` a valid argument for it? I mean, you can call a lot of methods with `this` (for example `MyMethod(this)`) so what make `typeof` and `sizeof` special?

This would be really useful when writing a snippet for stuff like a `DependencyProperty`. For example, look at the `propa` snippet. It has to use `typeof(ownerclass)` in there. It would be a lot better if it could be `typeof(this)` instead.

---

The test program:

```
using System;
public struct TestingClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        TestingClass tc = new TestingClass();
        tc.Test();
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
    public void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(this)); //error here
        Console.WriteLine(sizeof(this)); //and here too
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I mean, typeof is a method (or a keyword that you pass an argument to, not sure)

It's an operator, not a method. They're very different. After all, you can't use the *name* of a type as a method argument anywhere else, can you?

Both `typeof` and `sizeof` are unary operators with a single operand, which must be a type (or type parameter) name. `this` isn't a type name, hence the error.

I suggest you read the C# 5 specification on both of these operators - the `typeof` operator is described in section 7.6.11, and the `sizeof` operator is described in section 18.5.8.

If you want to know the execution-time type of an object, call [`Object.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx), which really *is* a method:

```
Type foo = this.GetType();
```

Or leave `this` implicit:

```
Type foo = GetType();
```

That *isn't* the same as the compile-time type of `this`, which is the type in which the code appears.

Comment: @EdS.: Yes - I figured that I'd leave that out to avoid further complications.

Comment: Inside a non-sealed class (structs are always sealed) `TestingClass`, use `typeof(TestingClass)` to get that type. The method `GetType()` will get the actual runtime type of this instance, and that might be different from `typeof(TestingClass)`.

Answer (score 1):

The "this" keyword refers to the current instance of the class,and typeof requires a type not instance(the type of "the" instance)

```
Type t = this.GetType();
```

CIL loads the "hidden" argument "this" ,which refers to the current type, in the method implementation,and calls the default base class ctor for the "this" object(this happens for non-static members).

sizeof may be applied to value types and unmanaged types like pointers
see msdn link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf(v=vs.100).aspx